# Why is linespacing different if using subitem vs no subitem in beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize, subitem

I have list in beamer, where one item has a subitem, the other not.
The spacing between lines is larger for the one without subitem.

How can I make the spacing the same?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\Large
\begin{itemize}
\item a top item very long break by now any minute now now noasdjkfhh ajsdhkfhl khasdklfn anl
\item a top item very long break by now any minute now now noasdjkfhh ajsdhkfhl khasdklfn anl
\begin{itemize}
\item Hello
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Line spacing differnet dependent on subitem or not]

Comment: Is the question **Why?** or rather **How to avoid it?**?